# Table containing micro-averaged and macro-averaged F1-scores

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder that contains 5 different folders, where each folder has 50 email documents belonging to a particular topic (so, there are a total of 5 topics/classes).

Train two classifiers – a Decision Tree, and an SVC (with linear kernel). Report microaveraged and macro-averaged F1-scores of 10-fold cross-validation. You may need to preprocess the data, prune the decision tree, and find good C values for SVC

Can you help me with Table containing micro-averaged and macro-averaged F1-scores.

I tried putting the mails per folder in one txt file but still when I doing the decision tree the process is not letting me do it.

unable to the get the results..

Should I put all the files in a said folder into one text file?

```
with open ("C:/Users/*******/DS Assign/toclassify/cwx.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for f in files:
        with open(f) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)

path = ("C:/Users/*******/DS Assign/toclassify/ra/*")
files = glob.glob(path)

#print(files)

with open ("C:/Users/*******/DS Assign/toclassify/ra.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for f in files:
        with open(f) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)

path = ("C:/Users/*******/DS Assign/toclassify/rsh/*")
files = glob.glob(path)

#print(files)

with open ("C:/Users/*******/DS Assign/toclassify/rsh.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for f in files:
        with open(f) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)


path = ("C:/Users/*******/DS Assign/toclassify/src/*")
files = glob.glob(path)

#print(files)

with open ("C:/Users/*******/DS Assign/toclassify/src.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for f in files:
        with open(f) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)

path = ("C:/Users/*******/DS Assign/toclassify/tpm/*")
    files = glob.glob(path)

    #print(files)
```

Comment: are you trying to read 50 text files from 5 folders and consolidating them for modelling later on?

What format do you want it to be stored into?

Comment: I am not sure what would be the best approach for this.kindly advise

Comment: it's a bit hard to help if I don't know what is in the text file :) A sample would be appreciated

Comment: https://github.com/VijayPulijala/Classifier_sample/

Comment: The above link has a zip folder which has all the files..

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

data_dir = os.path.join('.', 'data')

data_ids = []
data_txt = []

# Create a helper function to read the data from a  particular folder and file
def get_data(file_name, folder_dir):
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_dir, file_name)
    return open(file_path, 'r').read()

# Loop through each folder in the data directory
for folder in os.listdir(data_dir):
    # Create the folder directory from the data directory
    folder_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, folder)

    # Store the IDs of each file in the particular folder directory into a list
    data_ids += os.listdir(folder_dir)

    # Using list comprehension to create a list of the text contained in each file
    # for a particular ID in the folder directory
    data_txt += [get_data(data_id, folder_dir) for data_id in os.listdir(folder_dir)]

# Store into a Pandas dataframe for easy integration into modelling packages

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': data_ids,
    'text': data_txt
})
```

Comment: forgot to mention that "data" contains the exact folders and files from your zip file